# Struts file upload not working with jar files in lib folder

Tags: java, file-upload, struts

Can someone help me please ? I am stuck and don't have any clue.

I want to upload a file in struts 1.2. I know that struts uses 'commons-io.jar' and 'commons-fileupload.jar' for file upload and I need to place these jars in WebContent / Web-INF / lib folder. I placed the jars in lib folder but application is giving class definition not found error.
I tried creating a lib folder and placing these jar files under WEB-INF folder. I also tried adding these jar files in build path but still giving same below error.
I also tried using 3 differnet versions (1, 1.4, 2.4) of 'commons-io.jar'.

Can some one help please ?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.io.output.DeferredFileOutputStream
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:59)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.jenter code hereava:57)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:120)
```

Comment: The file should be in the `web-inf/lib` what is the contents of this folder?

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when the commons-io.jar is missing from your class path    Right Click on Your Project . and upload all latest version Commons jar files

- Right Click On Project.
- Go to Properties.
- Go to Library Tab.
- Add Jar .
- Clean and Build
- upload updated war file on tomcat webapp folder.
- start tomcat .         Hope this will Help Thanks